# I just need the right direction to move forward in creating a Multilpayer Toptrumps Game

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am trying to make a TopTrupms Card Game. I ended up with the cards and the Buttons of one player on the Stage. The second one is at the side. Because i want make a multiplayer game i have no concept how to move forward. **Should i make the second Player also playable and than try to make it multiplayer or should i try to make it multiplayer now with the currentcard?** ([Code](http://www.habits.wiki/hw/main.cs)) I cant understand how it is possible to show different cards to different players at the same stage in multiplayer and i cant find a tutorial that shows this. Its always about 3d stuff where all player see the same things on the same stage. So i dont know which way to go. Please can anyone move me in the right direction, give me a hint or tell me how i should exactly do it!!! I dont know how to describe my project correct but i try. I made two different lists with shuffled cards and their attributes in it, parsed from a txt file. all the numbers are linked to different objects in the game that are a background image and different Buttons to choose the Value you wanna play against the card of the other player. Till now the second player can not vote and the first player is always at the turn. should i

[Here](http://www.habits.wiki/hw/main.cs) is the Code and sorry for bad anotations, i am a absolut noob on this and just learning the basics of Unity and C# but i cant wrap my head around this Topic for any reason...

Please give me a hint!

Comment: If you have any code relevant to your question, please put it *in* the question. Content on external sites can't be relied on to stick around, so if it's an integral part of your question, it must be *in* the question. If you have doubts about how to describe your project, write a first draft and read it. If it's an incoherent jumble of vague ideas, revise it until it is both coherent, and specific. [This article may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you write code the way you write prose, you're in trouble. You must learn to organize your thoughts.

Comment: Finally, this is much too broad. We do much better with specific and concrete implementation problems here, as long as they don't involve null reference exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is more design based.

Read about the Entity-Component design pattern.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system

Basically think of an implementation like so, in your game you will have a list of Entities. Each Frame these entities will all update. 
In the update function of your entities your entities will update all their components.
Your Player entities will have input components, but which input component will be decided at run time, either NetworkedInput, LocalInput, AiInput etc.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The anwser is [Network.isClient](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network-isClient.html) to make it multiplayer right away with the currentcard.
This is the way how i will do it. I jurst write every functions of the currentcard inside this if and els function for both players.

It should be the anwser i was searching for.

Thanks for the hints. They are very valuable for me.
@Ed Plunkett I hope i can present my next question more concrete and more on the point. It was hard for me to get a basic understanding of networking programming and i am so happy i got it now. Its always so easy afterwards.